# C++ generating a variable number of nested FOR-loops

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have a struct containing a vector of elements:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    std::vector<Element> vec;
};
```

each Element contains a container:

```
struct Element
{
    Container m_container;
};
```

The vector can contain 3, 4 or 5 `Element`s. This is guaranteed.

If there are 3 items, the next stage contains a series of 3 nested `for` loops (see below). A vector with 4 elements required 4 loops, 5 -> 5 loops etc. There will only be 3, 4 or 5 loops.

I have to omit some code but the logic within the loops concludes with multiplying the doubles together and calculating a minimum. So the inner-most loop needs access to the local variables from the earlier loops.

```
for(const auto& x : vec[0].m_container)
{
    const double some_calc = some_func(x);

    for(const auto& y : vec[1].m_container)
    {
        const double some_calc_2 = some_func(y);

        for(const auto& z : vec[2].m_container)
        {
            const double some_calc_3 = some_func(z);

            // TODO need a way to generate 4th and 5th loops if required

            // Logic processing data from the 3 loops
            const double a_calculation = some_calc * some_calc_2 * some_calc_3;
            double a_min = some_calc;
            a_min = std::min(a_min, some_calc_2);
            a_min = std::min(a_min, some_calc_3);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can automate/generate these nested FOR Loops, depending on the size of the vector? I was thinking of something templated like this:

```
if(struct.vec.size() == 3)
{
    the_answer<3>(struct.vec);
}
else if(struct.vec.size() == 4)
{
    the_answer<4>(struct.vec);
}
else
{
    the_answer<5>(struct.vec);
}
```

Comment: Consider using recursion, where each recursive call implements (at most) one loop.   Remember that every case for which which recursion can occur (in your case, the size of the vector is 3,4, or 5) needs to eventually meet a defined condition for *ending* the recursion, otherwise the recursion can be infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve solve this problems most of the times with recursion. so

```
void loop(int n,const vector<double>& vec, vector<double> outer_vars){
     if (n!=vec.size()){
         for(const auto& z : vec[n]){
             outer_vars.push_back(some_func(z));
             loop(n+1,vec,outer_vars);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a recursive function.

```
void loop(const std::vector<Element>& vec, size_t idx) {
  if (idx + 1 == vec.size()) {
    for (const auto& z : vec[idx].m_container) {
      const double some_calc = some_func(z);

      // Logic processing data from the innermost loop
      const double a_calculation = some_calc * some_calc_2 * some_calc_3;
      double a_min = some_calc;
      a_min = std::min(a_min, some_calc_2);
      a_min = std::min(a_min, some_calc_3);
    }
  } else {
    for (const auto& z : vec[idx].m_container) {
      const double some_calc = some_func(z);
      loop(vec, idx + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Somewhere start

```
loop(vec, 0);
```

Comment: I missed `some_calc * some_calc_2 * some_calc_3`, you can adopt the functions, for example by passing `some_calc * arg_some_calc` to `arg_some_calc` in the function.